# How to call a function when user click on browser window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I have a `proceed to payment` button and it redirect to `redirectPayment.html` page as `target = _blank` and do payment operations there, so I had set a flag `creditsRefresh` as `Yes` by local storage once payment is triggered. Now when payment is successfull , it will redirect to success jsp page.so user can close the tab and come back to original tab where payment initiated.But I want my amount to be refreshed after payment. So I need to call a function when user click on window if `creditsRefresh` is `yes` .I tried doing `onFocus` or `onBlur` , it doesnt worked.

payment.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="initiatePayment(CreditDetails);">Proceed to pay</button>
```

Paymentcontroller.js

```
$scope.initiatePayment = function(){
 $window.localStorage.setItem('creditsRefresh','yes');
 $window.open('/redirectPayment','_blank');
}
```

After success payment:
`$scope.myCredits` is the function which will refresh my amount after payment.

```
 $scope.focusOnPageCall = function(){    
            if ($window.localStorage.getItem('creditsRefresh') == 'yes'){
                $scope.myCredits();
              $window.localStorage.setItem('creditsRefresh' ,'no');
}}

    $window.onfocus = $scope.focusOnPageCall();
```

Answer (score 0):

I given ng-click and called the function .

```
<div class = "wrapper" ng-click = "focusOnPageCall()">
<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="initiatePayment(CreditDetails);">Proceed to pay</button>

</div>
</div>
```

it worked